# Is there no official driver for AMD 6370M for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Is there no official driver for AMD 6370M for Ubuntu 18.04  ?

Nothing as per [site](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-6370m).

While installing the above (latest available is for 14.04) it complained of missing libgcc1. Even on installing the later, the driver was not successfully installed.

Is the open source driver sufficient ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "installable" driver for 18.04.

The kernel module is sufficient.